# curl command line ssl session reuse

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, libcurl

session reuse in ssl is quite common and curl is widely used also in command line. It surely should have an option to save a SSL/TLS session id to a file and then reuse it on the next call...

Using curl in areas where mobile transfers are not cheap this is kind of a must.

Does anyone know of any possiblity to implement this or it maybe is already somewhere available?

In openssl this isn't to hard (read or store session to file )

```
Setting session from previous attempt:
SSL_SESSION* session = d2i_SSL_SESSION(NULL, &readFromFile,fileLen);
SSL_set_session(cSSL, session );
SSL_SESSION_free(cachedSession);

Storing session from current connection:
SSL_SESSION* session = SSL_get1_session(cSSL)
int len = i2d_SSL_SESSION(session, NULL); //get needed size
unsigned char *file_data = new char[len]
len = i2d_SSL_SESSION(session, &file_data );
//Store to file file_data of len
```

For crude command line operation you do not need to store host and port, to know to which host the session belongs, but let user take care of it.

So curl would come with 1 or maybe 2 flags

```
--ssl-session-file @file
```

or

```
--ssl-session-file @existing_session_file and --ssl-session-save-file @new_session_file
```

Can this be done ?
This would make commandline curl and libcurl even more useful in limited mobile networks...

Is this possible to add?

With kind regards,

Comment: @DanielStenberg Looks like curl from the command line does this already  (based on man page info about `--no-sessionid`), correct?.  This of course is only the case if you pass multiple url's on the command line so the same handle is re-used for subsequent requests.  Obviously libcurl will do this, which is probably what the OP should be using for any type of advanced usage.

Comment: yes, curl (and libcurl) will do session id resumption when the handle is reused but I assumed the question here was saving the ID between separate curl command line invokes.

Comment: @DanielStenberg exactly storing session into file between command calls or lib calls