# Pre-create connections in libcurl connection pool

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

During startup my application does some expensive time consuming initialization and then it establishes ssl connections to multiple domains (multiple connections to some of these domains). From looking at wireshak traces it takes at best 150-200ms for the ssl connection to be established.

Can I somehow tell curl to establish in advance one ssl connection to `abc.com` and 3 ssl connections to `xyz.com`?
What options do I have? I can make some bogus requests to these domains, but I'd rather avoid doing that not to pollute servers with bogus requests. As a last resort I could possibly do http OPTIONS requests to these domains.

Comment: "150-200ms" - that sounds like the typical latency for an internet-wide TLS connection given the 3-way handshake. If that's the case, then preemptively creating a TLS connection to the remote host might not actually save you time because the remote host might close inactive connections after a period of inactivity so you'll need to redo the process (taking 150-200ms anyway) all over again.

Comment: You want to resume the previous TLS session on the next connection (session reuse). This should be something you enable in your SSL stack.

Comment: @Dai In my case I have millions of connections made from mobiles worldwide. 150-200 is the best case, worst case is somewhere in seconds perhaps. My startup time could be around 500ms, so during startup I can create TLS these connections so by the time I'm ready to use them they would be already created or in progress to be created.

Comment: @jxh In my case this a new process started, where I didn't have previous connections. I only want to make these connection in advance

Comment: Although libcurl may not support it, your TLS library should have APIs to allow you to save the session ID cache to a file, and reload the cache on the next start up. In terms of pre-populating, you have to send a request, but you can send a `HEAD` request, which should be low overhead.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857881/curl-command-line-ssl-session-reuse) has an example of how to load and save session state for a particular connection.

Comment: Are you using multi mode for your connections?

Comment: I dont know how much access you have to the underlying ssl objects in libcurl, but basically you would need to call non-blocking `SSL_connect` during your initialization in plain sockets/openssl and then poll for connection established. These connections would usually last up to 15s. Further, depending on the domains you are connecting to, you should limit the amount of concurrent connections in your connection pool to a browser like value, else you gonna be blacklisted sooner or later.

Comment: @OZ17 I'm connecting to my own servers.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, I use curl multi interface, but even for easy interface it would probably be applicable as long as you don't try to create more connections than libcurl caches per handle.

Comment: @jxh It's a bit different. After I already had connection libcurl either keeps connections open or resumes them quickly. The first connection however always takes a lot of time. In my case I start making these connections after some time (assume 500ms) from executable startup. So during these 500ms of executable startup I'd like to find a way to pre-create these ssl connections.

Comment: I had explained using `HEAD` to pre-populate the connection pool, but I was explaining that if you save and restore the client session state, you can speed up the connection establishment when your process restarts.

Comment: In my case saving and restoring connection state is not an option. I only wanted to know if there was a way to `pre-create connections in libcurl connection pool`. Using `HEAD` or `OPTIONS` http requests is a fallback approach if libcurl doesn't provide direct way to initiate ssl connections in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since established connections will be kept in curl's [connection cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944414/93747) for a while after transfers, I would suggest you simply do a simple `HEAD` request (using [CURLOPT_NOBODY](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOBODY.html)) or an `OPTIONS` one, then while starting up the rest of the things so then the "real" request and reuse that connection.

Comment: What about options request? Anything against that?

Comment: To handle possible case where I might start my actual ssl requests before the HEAD/OPTIONS completed probably I'd need to enable pipelining to ensure that these ssl connections would be reused even if there are uncompleted requests in progress.

Comment: That should work equally well for connection purposes. Just that you need to set a string then ("OPTIONS") with libcurl's API and not just a boolean.